# Getting window.location.href to return page name and extension if URL ends with a / slash

Tags: javascript, url, location

When using `window.location.href` on a page that ends with a `/` (a default.aspx lets say) the result is simply returning:

```
http://localhost/
```

I've been looking everywhere, but how can I get it to actually return the true URL?

```
http://localhost/default.aspx
```

Looking at the window.location object, the only options I see are:

```
hash: ""
host: "localhost"
hostname: "localhost"
href: "http://localhost/"
origin: "http://localhost"
pathname: "/"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
```

Comment: As far as the client is concerned that is the "true url" if the web server has served content with just http:// localhost/ and it "knows" that default.aspx is a 'default' document to return to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the true URL; even if there is another URL that gives you the same information, (`/my-page/` and `/my-page/index.html`) they're all JavaScript will know about. So unfortunately you can't sniff the server side tech that way.

Of course if you were desperate to know if `/my-page/default.aspx` was the same as `/my-page/` you could call it asynchronously and if you get a 200 back, you could compare it's contents. **That's definitely not something I'd recommend though**.

Comment: Agreed, I definitely don't want to be doing any sort of AJAX for this, I think I'll just hard-code the `default.aspx` part into the Ajax URL in these crazy instances. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Default document is set sever-side and the name is not accessible via JavaScript.

A workaround might be to get the name of the page server-side and pass it to the client (e.g. in a hidden field or JS variable).